# Encrypt csv file with certificate using Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have to automate the encryption of csv files. I decided to use following method:

```
Protect-CmsMessage -To $certificatePath -Path $inputPath -OutFile $encryptedFilePath
```

The content of file is encrypted and I can read it using

```
Unprotect-CmsMessage -Path .\encrypted.cms
```

How can I save the content as a .csv file? I tried:

```
Unprotect-CmsMessage -Path .\book.cms  | Export-Csv output.csv
```

But `output.csv` contains only following information:

[image]

Comment: It's already a csv file, pipe to `Out-File` or `Set-Content` instead

Comment: Mathiass thank you for suggestion. Set-Content was the thing I was searching for :)